# Domain controllers won't replicate

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, domain, domain-controller, replication

I recently removed a secondary domain controller (forcefully) and created a new one as secondary for the same domain.

The problem is, is that the new secondary can see the primary and itself, but the primary can't see the new secondary.

Dcdiag on the primary DC reveals:

```
  Starting test: VerifyReferences
     Some objects relating to the DC VIEW-A have problems:
        [1] Problem: Missing Expected Value
         Base Object:
        CN=NTDS Settings,CN=VIEW-A,CN=Servers,CN=Stafford-HQ,CN=Sites,CN=Con
figuration,DC=ea-hq,DC=com
         Base Object Description: "DSA Object"
         Value Object Attribute Name: serverReferenceBL
         Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
         Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862

        [1] Problem: Missing Expected Value
         Base Object: CN=VIEW-A,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=ea-hq,DC=com
         Base Object Description: "DC Account Object"
         Value Object Attribute Name: frsComputerReferenceBL
         Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
         Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862

     ......................... VIEW-A failed test VerifyReferences
```

And on the new secondary:

```
  Starting test: Replications
     REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
     ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
     Source VIEW-A
     Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
     This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
     REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
     ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
     Source VIEW-A
     Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
     This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
     REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
     ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
     Source VIEW-A
     Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
     This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
     REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
     ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
     Source VIEW-A
     Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
     This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
     REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
     ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
     Source VIEW-A
     Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
     This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
     ......................... VIEW-C passed test Replications
  Starting test: RidManager
     ......................... VIEW-C passed test RidManager
  Starting test: Services
        Invalid service startup type: NtFrs on VIEW-C, current value
        DISABLED, expected value AUTO_START
        NtFrs Service is stopped on [VIEW-C]
     ......................... VIEW-C failed test Services
  Starting test: SystemLog
     A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x00000458
        Time Generated: 04/14/2015   10:57:47
        Event String:
        The Group Policy Client Side Extension Folder Redirection was unable
to apply one or more settings because the changes must be processed before system startup or user logon. The system will wait for Group Policy processing to finish completely before the next startup or logon for this user, and this may result in slow startup and boot performance.
     A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x00001695
        Time Generated: 04/14/2015   11:36:38
        Event String:
        Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associat
ed with DNS domain 'ea-hq.com.' failed.  These records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application partition).
     A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x00001695
        Time Generated: 04/14/2015   11:36:38
        Event String:
        Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associat
ed with DNS domain 'ForestDnsZones.ea-hq.com.' failed.  These records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application partition).
     A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x00001695
        Time Generated: 04/14/2015   11:36:38
        Event String:
        Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associat
ed with DNS domain 'DomainDnsZones.ea-hq.com.' failed.  These records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application partition).
     ......................... VIEW-C passed test SystemLog
  Starting test: VerifyReferences
     Some objects relating to the DC VIEW-C have problems:
        [1] Problem: Missing Expected Value
         Base Object: CN=VIEW-C,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=ea-hq,DC=com
         Base Object Description: "DC Account Object"
         Value Object Attribute Name: frsComputerReferenceBL
         Value Object Description: "SYSVOL FRS Member Object"
         Recommended Action: See Knowledge Base Article: Q312862

     ......................... VIEW-C failed test VerifyReferences
```

I have googled and googled but I still can't get it working properly.

The primary DC is windows 2008, the secondary is 2012.

How can I at least fix these problems found in dcdiag? Are these problems responsible for the primary DC not being able to replicate to the secondary or is that a separate issue?

---

Tried adding the DC manually on the primary DC:

[image]

Comment: well, did you try what dcdiag told you to try?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312862

Comment: @Lenniey Yes and with no luck. It is a live environment so I can't be messing around with DCPromo and risk having no one being able to log in. Please see my edit as I have tried adding the DC manually.

Comment: I suppose the dcpromo on the secondary DC went through without any problems. If so, I'd try to delete the seconday DC again, use a new hostname and DNS record / IP and add it to the domain again. (just like 0x0000001E said)

Comment: Did you reuse the name and IP?  What caused you to fail the normal dc demotion?

Comment: @JimB I can't remember 100% if I did demote it properly or not, I think I would have as there was no hardware failure etc. We just wanted to upgrade to server 2012. I Don't really understand why the primary would not see a new DC which sees itself and the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used the same hostname and IP address for the secondary? If so you need to remove the secondary as a DC, remove all GUID/references in DNS/ADDS to the old name...or you can use a unique name.